# How can I remotely access Blender 2.8?

Tags: rendering, gpu, network

I am trying to remotely access Blender in a host server.

Both client PC and host server have Nvidia GPUs installed that are compatible with Blender. Blender works properly in both PCs if they were accessed physically not remotely. When I am trying to access Blender remotely in the host server, however, Blender does not start running and I get the error message below.

"Blender - Unsupported Graphics Card or Driver: A graphics card and driver with support for OpenGL 3.3 or higher is required. Installing the latest driver for your graphics card may resolve the issue. The program will now close."

I checked the GPU driver versions of both the client PC and the host server. They are all updated to the latest versions.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem? Appreciated.

Client workstation: Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2125 CPU @ 4.00 GHz with one NIVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti. Windows 10 Enterprise.

Host Server: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4216 CPU @ 2.10 GHz with NIVIDIA TITAN RTXs. Windows Server 2019.

I am accessing the server using the default "Remote desktop connection" Windows application.
[image: OpenGL error]

Comment: Can you provide the hardware information from both the host and client workstations?

Comment: Could you edit the question and provide detail information about your problem? How are you accessing the server remotely? What operating systems are you using? That's kind of essential part of the question that should not be skipped. People will only be able to help you if you describe your problem in full.

Comment: @nathan Thank you for pointing out! Kindly check the updated question body. Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: @martynas Thank you for pointing out! Kindly check the updated question body. Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Windows remote desktop connection application does not use the GPU to display the screen somehow. You could try some other application for remote connection. I use Google's Chrome Remote Desktop(that is free) and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Thank you! It's working.

Comment: RDP, the protocol windows uses for remote desktop does not support OpenCL or CUDA natively. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705471/current-state-and-solutions-for-opengl-over-windows-remote

Answer (score 0):

using mesa3d from https://github.com/pal1000/mesa-dist-win
and you can remotely access Blender 2.8